# selenium execute_script() returns incorrect value

Tags: python, selenium, youtube, selenium-chromedriver

I performed code below on a floating page like https://www.youtube.com/user/JFlaMusic/videos with python selenium chromedriver. But code was performed incorrectly. 
I expected to go to the end of page, but `last_height` and `new_height` were same at first while condition loop. so `break` was performed.
why does this result occur?

```
last_height = self.driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
print(last_height)
while True:
    self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    new_height = self.driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
    print(new_height)
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `time.sleep(0.5)` which looks quite unreliable, try to implement ExplicitWait as below to wait until page scrolled:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

last_height = self.driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
print(last_height)
while True:
    self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight);")
    try:
        wait(self.driver, 5).until(lambda driver: self.driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight") > last_height)
    except TimeoutException:
        break
    last_height = self.driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
```